# Prove or give a counter example $(A \oplus B) \cap B^C = A\setminus (A \cap B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove or give a counter example $(A \oplus B) \cap B^C = A\setminus (A \cap B)$

---

$\oplus$ denotes the symmetric difference

I did venn diagram to check if they are equal and I got that they are equal according to the diagram I got that the result is $A \setminus B$ but obviously this is not a proof so I tried the following:

right side: $A \setminus (A \cap B) \iff A \cap (A \cap B)^C \iff A \cap (A^C \cup B^C) \iff A \cap A^C \cup A \cap B^C \iff \emptyset \cup A \cap B^C \iff A\setminus B$

left side: $(A \oplus B) \cap B^C \iff (A \cup B) \cap (A \cap B)^C \cap B^C \iff (A \cup B) \cap (A^C \cup B^C)\cap B^C \iff \emptyset \cap B^C$

is the conclusion from the venn diagram that they are equal correct? if so which part am I doing wrong

Thanks for any help and tips !

Comment: Your mistake is to say (near the end of your work on the left side) that $(A \cup B) \cap (A^C \cup B^C) \iff \emptyset$. It would be true that $(A \cup B) \cap (A \cup B)^C \iff \emptyset$, but that's not what you have.

Comment: You should say that $\oplus$ denotes the symmetric difference (knowing that there exists another notation $\Delta$)

Comment: @tomi How can I approach it ? I also tried distributive property on $(A^C \cup B^C) \cap B^C$ but I seem to always get the wrong answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the one hand,
$$
A \oplus B \cap B^c = ((A \backslash B) \cup (B \backslash C)) \cap B^c = ((A \backslash B) \cap B^c) \cup (B \backslash C \cap B^c) = (A \backslash B) \cap B^c = A \backslash B.
$$
On the other hand
$$
A \backslash (A \cap B) = A \cap (A \cap B)^c = A \cap (A^c \cup B^c) = A \cap B^c = A \backslash B.
$$